# How to import FFmpeg into Android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, ffmpeg, repository

I'm trying to convert series of images into video.
For that I'm adding FFmpeg into my Android project.
However it is not adding properly, so I can't import class FFmpeg into the code.
in the statement "int rc = FFmpeg.execute(command);" FFmpeg is highlighted in red.

I think something wrong with libraries. Could you please give suggestion how import libraries correctly?

My Manifest file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TimelapseLite"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My settings.gradle file

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

}

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

}
rootProject.name = "TimelapseLite"
include ':app'

My build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'ae.vpdev.timelapselite'
    compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ae.vpdev.timelapselite"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.5.LTS'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

}

My code in MainActivity

```
private void convertImagesToVideo() {
    StringBuilder imageListFileContent = new StringBuilder();
    for (Uri imageUri : selectedImages) {
        imageListFileContent.append("file '").append(imageUri.getPath()).append("'\n");
    }

    try {
        File imageListFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "image_list.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(imageListFile);
        writer.append(imageListFileContent.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        File outputFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "output_video.mp4");
        String outputFilePath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();

        String command = "-f concat -safe 0 -i " + imageListFile.getAbsolutePath() +
                " -vf \"scale=-2:720\" -r 30 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p " + outputFilePath;

        int rc = FFmpeg.execute(command);

        if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d("FFmpeg", "Video conversion completed successfully");
            // Now you can use the outputFilePath to play or share the video
        } else {
            Log.d("FFmpeg", "Video conversion failed");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would not prefer to add the full FFMPEG SDK, as it increases the app size exponentially, however using [Arthenica's FFMPEG-KIT](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit) seems the easiest way to get FFMPEG into a project

```
implementation "com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1.LTS"
```

This new FFMPEG-KIT not only has a reduction in size, but the commands also execute quicker and have better async support and much easier implementation.

To use you just have to import

```
import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKit
import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.ReturnCode
```

and then :

```
FFmpegKit.executeAsync(cmdString , {
    when {
        ReturnCode.isSuccess(it.returnCode) -> {
            println("FFMPEG SUCCESS :${it.state.name}")
        }

        ReturnCode.isCancel(it.returnCode) -> {
            println("FFMPEG CANCELLED :${it.returnCode}")
        }

        it.returnCode.isValueError -> {
            println("FFMPEG ERROR :${it.logs.last()}")
        }
    }
} , {
    println("FFMEPG LOG :${it.message}")
} , {
    println("FFMEPG STATS :${it.speed}")
})
```

here `cmdString`, is a string of commands, your commands should work but the only issue I ran into was that I had to use `-y -i` instead of `-f` which seemed to run the commands.

Comment: when i am adding min-gpl instead of full, the apk size is actually bigger (by 14mb). ? :/